# Filter a list of files based on file attributes

Tags: shell, grep, find

With `find` you can search by file attributes like `-type`, `-executable` etc.

How to achieve something similar, but from an existing list of files? e.g. the output of `dpkg -L <package_name>`.

A pipe to `ls -ld` or `file` and then to `grep` is nor exact nor correct.

I assume that `awk` could be used to parse the output of `ls -ld` for an exact result, but this seems overly complicated and not a true general solution. The best scenario would be if `find` itself can be used for this.

Comment: Do you know about the `stat` command?

Comment: @JeffSchaller no. I just looked it up. It doesn't seem much different than the ` | xargs ls -ld | grep ... `, other than the fact that you can control the format (which is a +).

Comment: What attribute(s) are you looking for?

Comment: @JeffSchaller for instance, I want to show only executable files. Or only directories. But I am also interested in a general solution (the same thing you can do with find). The final output should be the initial file name received as input.

Comment: I would use stat; I'm not at a shell right now, so if no one has an answer by tomorrow I'll write one up.

Comment: @JeffSchaller ty

Comment: Perl would be another flexible choice. The main issue (coming from the "don't parse ls" idea) is that file names can contain a variety of interesting characters; so fixing the (picking a particular)  command (such as dpkg) is critical to dealing with its input.

Comment: Can we focus answers on the output of `dpkg-query -L <package_name>`?

Comment: @bolov using `stat` is hugely different from `xargs ls -ld | grep ` because it doesn't involving parsing the output of `ls` (and parsing ls is broken).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
stat --printf="'%n' is a %F\n" $(dpkg -L grep)
```

If you wanted to show only directories you could do:

```
stat --printf="'%n' is a %F\n" $(dpkg -L grep) | grep ' is a directory$'
```

or

```
for f in $(dpkg -L grep)
do
    operms=$(stat --format='0%a' "$f")
    if [ $(( $operms & 0111 )) -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "$f: executable";
    fi
done
```

The possibilities are endless!

I think the first two forms are generally more desirable because they only start two processes; however the `for` loop starts a `stat` process for each file.

See the `stat` man page in section 1 of the manual for all of the attributes you can access this way.

Thanks to @Jeff-Schaller for mentioning `stat`.

Comment: Nice!  I wanted to add that it can also be used in a pipe with the addition of  `xargs`, like so: `dpkg -L grep | xargs stat --printf="'%n' is a %F\n"`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `test` in a fairly analogous way to `find` e.g.

```
dpkg -L somepackage | while read -r f; do [ ! -d "$f" -a -x "$f" ] && printf "$f\n"; done
```

for `find ! -type d -executable`

Answer (score 0):

You could use my `dlocate` package with the `-lsbin` option:

e.g.

```
$ dlocate -lsbin gawk
/usr/bin/gawk
/usr/bin/igawk
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/awk/grcat
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/awk/pwcat
```

You could pipe that into `xargs ls -l` if you wanted a long listing.

I wrote `dlocate` as a wrapper around `dpkg` and `grep-dctrl` etc to do all these little things that `dpkg` couldn't do itself.  it's also a lot faster at searches than `dpkg -s`.

The current version of `dlocate` in the debian archives does evilly parse `ls`, which is relatively safe in this particular context.  An unreleased-so-far update uses `stat`...i'll probably finish working on it and get around to uploading that to debian by the end of the year.

btw, `dlocate` also has (amongst others) `-du`, `-lsconf`, `-lsman`, and `-md5check` options.

e.g.

```
$ dlocate -lsman gawk
/usr/share/man/man1/gawk.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/igawk.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/filefuncs.3am.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/fnmatch.3am.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/fork.3am.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/inplace.3am.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/ordchr.3am.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/readdir.3am.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/readfile.3am.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/revoutput.3am.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/revtwoway.3am.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/rwarray.3am.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/time.3am.gz
```

You can pipe that straight into `xargs man` and read the man pages one after another.

```
$ dlocate -lsman gawk | xargs man
```

Comment: btw, dlocate is a bash script so you can easily read it to find out how it works.